# How to run multiple conditionals in an RXJS subcription

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am getting data back from a modal, I need to check the result and determine which outside function to fire based on many conditions.

I've verified that the data being passed back is formatted correctly and the series of else if's should be getting triggered, but it looks like it will skip over all conditions and do nothing.

What is the most productive way to go about implementing this logic?

My code:

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    console.log('RESULT: ', result.delete);



    if (result.isNew && !result.cancel) {
      console.log('new story!');
      this.boardService.updateTasks(this.job.id, [
        ...this.job.tasks,
        result.task
      ]);
      this.closeStories('update', this.job)
    } 
    // means a delete has occured
    else if (result.delete) {
      this.closeStories('deleted triggered...')
      // last story has been deleted, prompt newStory
      if (this.stories.length < 2 && result === {}) {
        console.log('Last story was deleted!');
        this.closeStories('delete')
      }
      // a delete has happened
      else if (this.stories.length > 1 && result === {}) {
        console.log('A story was deleted!');
        this.closeStories('deletedLast')
      }
    }
    // means an update has occured
    else if (result.id && !result.isNew) {
      console.log('A story was Updated!');
      const update = this.stories;
      update.splice(result.index, 1, result.task);
      this.boardService.updateTasks(this.job.id, update);
      this.closeStories('update', this.job)
    }
    else if (result === undefined) {
      return 0
    }
    // this.closedStoryListEmitter.emit(this.job);
    console.log('hit close list event emitter!!');
  });
```

Comment: have you tried doing a series of if statements only?

Comment: @EJSulit yea and that seems to be working with just ifs

Comment: great! i just saw your comment, I thought you're away so I posted an answer, lol good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
//Have you checked other callbacks
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(
    result => {
        console.log('RESULT: ', result.delete); //does this console.log executes?
        //rest of the code
    },
    error=>{
        //do something with and error
    },
    ()=>{
        //finished
    }
);
```

Comment: im running the conditions on result. your example is what i have already

Comment: Yes, but your code will execute only if everything is alright with response. If there is an error in request, if server returns any 404 for example, your code won't run. It will look for error callback.

Comment: Yes that is correct, i stated previously in the question that im receiving expected values from result

Comment: Ok,  I wasn't sure about that, language barrier and stuff :) anyway, have you tried setting breakpoints to check where it stops executing? Since if you get right result the only thing I can think of is that you have issue in your conditions. Can you post result value?

Comment: thanks for the help! looks like the else was the issue. if i use plain "if" statement, it works

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want your if statements to be triggered, just do multiple if statements block without the else if block or at least that's how would I approach it.

```
...

if (result.isNew && !result.cancel) {
  console.log('new story!');
  this.boardService.updateTasks(this.job.id, [
    ...this.job.tasks,
    result.task
  ]);
  this.closeStories('update', this.job)
} 

if (result.delete) {
  this.closeStories('deleted triggered...')
  // last story has been deleted, prompt newStory
  if (this.stories.length < 2 && result === {}) {
    console.log('Last story was deleted!');
    this.closeStories('delete')
  }
  // a delete has happened
  else if (this.stories.length > 1 && result === {}) {
    console.log('A story was deleted!');
    this.closeStories('deletedLast')
  }
}

if (result.id && !result.isNew) {
  console.log('A story was Updated!');
  const update = this.stories;
  update.splice(result.index, 1, result.task);
  this.boardService.updateTasks(this.job.id, update);
  this.closeStories('update', this.job)
}

if (result === undefined) {
  return 0
}

...
```